# Book for Anti Design Patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, anti-patterns

I have heard a lot about anti patterns and would like to read a book on this,which book would you suggest for Anti patterns.

Comment: Big than you for asking non-constructive questions on stackoverflow - they are most valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Daily WTF](http://www.thedailywtf.com) is always a good place to find some choice examples of antipatterns.

Answer (score 6):

There actually is a book called *AntiPatterns*.  The supporting website includes a good overview of its contents, so you can decide whether it is worth buying.  [Find out more](http://www.antipatterns.com/).

Comment: +1 for this book - it's really good. Especially the "lava flow" anti pattern - so so relevant for working on a code base that's been around for any length of time.

Answer (score 5):

There is also this book specifically on sql anti patterns:
  [SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming 
by Bill Karwin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)

Read more at
  http://pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns

Answer (score 2):

[Anti-Patterns](http://www.antipatterns.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Bug Patterns In Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590590619)